# Lerna / Nx / Turborepo or other monorepo systems for non-js apps (php)

Tags: javascript, monorepo, lerna, nrwl-nx

I have repository with `/frontend` (JS/Vue) and `/backend` (PHP) and `docker-compose.yml` for development. But now I need to add another JS frontend that will be sharing some components, libs etc. I do not want to repeat code, so I found that I can use many tools for this like `lerna`, `nx`, `turborepo` and more for managing monorepo with shared packages.

Problem is that all tutorials and example repos I found are based on 100% JS repos, like React on front + Nest on back etc.

So question - using for ex. `nx` makes sense on repos with multiple languages, just to leverage it on JS packages? If yes, how directory structure should look like? Or maybe there are better monorepo tools that are designed for multiple languages, not just JS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use Angular and PHP (Yii Framework) inside an Nx monorepo and both works fine. No idea how Lerna and Turborepo works, but Nx allow running CLI commands, I use that for the PHP part. My monorepo looks a bit as follow:

```js
- apps // <- folder holding my projects
--- project-1
--- project-2
------ web // <- Main frontend app (Angular/JS)
------ electron // <- other JS apps like mobile, capacitor, extension, ...
------ api // <- PHP api overridden config files

- libs
--- web // <- shared JS stuff, most people call it 'shared' folder instead
------ ui // <- my shared design system
--- electron
--- project-2 // <- specific project overrides and locally shared stuff
------ services
------ data-access 
------ ui
--------- button // <- overriding a component from my design system to only apply in project-2
------ api // <- PHP api but only holding overridden files
--- php
------ api // <- shared PHP api code
------ auth // <- another shared PHP app
------ shell // <- another shared PHP app

- dist // <- is where NX will will put all generated code from all apps/libs
```

The main idea is that, every code I write goes inside that `libs` folder (libs/web for JS and libs/php for PHP) and within a generated Nx library so it has a name (like `php-api`) to link it from everywhere and a `project.json` file holding Nx configs.

That is my base shared code. Written once, for any project or lib needing it.

`libs/project-2` will then hold **project-2** specific code. Things that are only shared inside that app pages plus things I override from the previously mentioned folders (or previous shared layer) like the button example above.

Code inside `apps` is as tiny as possible, mainly layouts and configs. That is pretty much how most Nx documentation/tutorials out there would suggest (for JS). I do the same for PHP:

1. I've put all of my Yii api code inside `libs/php/api`
2. Everything specific to the **project-2** app (like models, controllers, ...) folders and/or files goes inside `libs/project-2/api`
3. main config files (like .env) goes inside `apps/project-2/api`
4. Each lib folder needed a `project.json` file defining it:

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "library",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/php/api",
  "tags": ["scope:php", "type:api"]
}
```

5. In my case, using Angular, there was an `angular.js` file at root level, where I declared each PHP lib name so Nx detects it, I simply added 2 lines: `"php-api": "libs/php/api"` and `"project-2-api": "libs/project-2/api",`
6. Inside `apps/project-2/api` folder, I added a `project.json` file with the following content:

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/project-2/api",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "mkdir -p dist/apps/project-2",
          "rsync -rtul libs/php/api dist/apps/project-2",
          "rsync -rtul libs/project-2/api dist/apps/project-2",
          "rsync -rtul apps/project-2/api dist/apps/project-2"
        ],
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "dependsOn": ["build"],
      "options": {
        "commands": ["php -S localhost:8081 -t dist/apps/project-2/api/web"]
      }
    }
  },
  "implicitDependencies": ["php-api"]
}
```

That defines both *build* and *serve* scripts, so I can use Nx cli to run them, the first will just copy PHP files to *dist* folder (respecting my overriding hierarchy) while the second uses PHP's built-in server to serve the final folder:

`> nx run project-2-api:build`

`> nx run project-2-api:serve`

Note that my first script uses `rsync -rtul` to copy files, you can use `cp -R` instead, I just found rsync much faster as it has the ability (with those options) to skip unchanged files.

So main idea is that, Most of my code is written once, overrides when needed, a single design system I only override its CSS for a different look with a new app. And I do the same for PHP, even if not directly supported, I simply use `nx:run-commands` executer for things like moving files, building or deploying live.

#### Auto update on save

I use VSCode, other IDE may also have a similar way, in my case I use an external extension called [run-on-save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save) that executes commands when saving a file based on provided regex. Its configuration for my project looks a bit as follow:

```json
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "match": "(/(project-2|php)/(api|yii-shared)/.+).php$",
        "cmd": "nx run project-2-api:build --skip-nx-cache"
      },
      {
        "match": "(/(project-2|php)/(auth|yii-shared)/.+).php$",
        "cmd": "nx run project-2-auth:build --skip-nx-cache"
      },
      {
        "match": "(/(project-2|php)/(shell|yii-shared)/.+).php$",
        "cmd": "nx run project-2-shell:build --skip-nx-cache"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Every time I hit CTR+S to save a PHP file, `dist` folder is automatically updated.